# Optimal wager strategy for high win chance / high odds game

Tags: statistics, gambling

In a rigged game of chance where statistically I am expected to win, is there a difference between betting the same amount of money each time (for example using Kelly criterion) vs using variable wager strategies like Martingale or anti-Martingale strategy?
For example could I expect to win more when doubling my bet with each win, vs making each bet the same amount?
As an example we can say that I am playing a game with 80% chance of winning \$1.3 for each \$1 bet (13:10 odds).

Comment: It depends on your preferences I'd imagine, for example risk tolerance.

Comment: Thanks, but this is very unspecific, and is actually a part of the question. Let's say I decide on my specific risk tolerance. Then what? I still would need to know if there is a difference between various wagering strategies, in terms of winning more using one strategy vs another, and having higher risk using one strategy vs another.